# Select Key from MongoDB key value pair

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform lookup on MongoDb between two collections where one of the fields as attribute as an key-value pair where i have to choose only key as my local field parameter.

Sample Json:

**key of the below json**

```
{    "distributions" : {
        "5cf88" : "5d023d4aa", 
        "5cfaca42e" : "5d0093a", 
        "5d023d490d" : "5d22abc69093a"
    }
}
```

**_id field of the below json:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5d22abc69093a", 
    "activatedBy" : {
        "id" : "5bc53813055aec", 
        "name" : "Test1", 
        "roles" : [
            "root"
        ]
    }
}
```

Lookup query:

```
$lookup: {
        from: 'collecection1',
        localField: 'distributions.key',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'Join'
    }
```

How to get they key form distributions to use for lookup as i need only key of as my join parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get they key form distributions to use for lookup as i need
>   only key of as my join parameter?

This aggregation query can do that using the [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) aggregation operator:

```
db.collection1.aggregate( [
 { $addFields: { fieldNameValues: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
 { $unwind: "$fieldNameValues" },
 { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldNameValues.v" } , "object" ] } } },
 { $addFields: { objs: { $objectToArray: "$fieldNameValues.v" } } },
 { $unwind: "$objs" },
 { $project: { distributions: "$objs"  } },
 { $lookup: {
        from: 'collection2',
        localField: 'distributions.v',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'Join'
   }
 }
] )
```

where:

*collection1*:

```
{ "distributions" : {
        "5cf88" : "5d023d4aa", 
        "5cfaca42e" : "5d0093a", 
        "5d023d490d" : "5d22abc69093a"
    }
}
```

*collection2*:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5d22abc69093a", 
    "activatedBy" : {
        "id" : "5bc53813055aec", 
        "name" : "Test1", 
        "roles" : [
            "root"
        ]
    }
}
```